# Xamarin iOS designer view gives error "Apple iOS SDK version 7.0 or newer is required to render this document, but it is unavailable."

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

While adding new project to my existing solution file in Visual Studio 2012, I am getting error "**Apple iOS SDK version 7.0 or newer is required to render this document, but it is unavailable.**" while loading .storyboard design file.

I've followed below checkpoints but none helped:

- Checked build host provider is connected or not. It is already connected
- SDK is synchronized in Visual Studio 2012 -> Tool -> Options -> Xamarin -> iOS Settings

Can anyone please help to get rid of the above mentioned error?

Thanks.

**Edit**

The error was automatically resolved by closing all the instance of the Visual Studio 2012 and reloading the entire solution and without even updating the XCode version on my MAC OS X Maverick machine.

Comment: It's telling you that you can't open an iOS storyboard in Visual Studio.

Comment: What is the solution to open .storyboard designer file? Because if I am creating new separate project for test, then it allows me to open design file .storyboard. But not in the existing solution in which I've to add new project for iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check timezone settings in both Windows [in which Visual Studio is installed] and MAC PC [in which Build Host Provider is installed].